# can i use switch between my cable modem and wireless router?

Tags: networking

My current network setup is:

cable modem ==> netgear fast ethernet switch ==> wireless router.

I can not access the internet after connecting to the wireless router. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if your cable modem (as any i've seen), doesn't do NAT , and your ISP doesn't give you a few public IPs(likely doesn't), then definitely not.  Otherwise, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Your cable box can only have one client. That should be the wireless router. Connect the cable box directly to the wireless router's WAN (or Internet) port. Then connect one of the wireless router's LAN ports to your switch.

Answer (score 0):

Check the routers web interface and the internet/WAN settings so you have a connection there. Also make sure Your cable from the switch goes straight into the WAN port of the router.

Answer (score 0):

There are, unfortunately, about a dozen things that can keep a computer from talking to a wireless router.  First step, though, is to make sure your computer's "radio" is turned on.

Can you access wireless anywhere else, such as in a mall food court (assuming this is a laptop)?

Also, add a tag for your OS, and in your post identify the brand and type of your computer.